# Downloading unencrypted data with Android app

Tags: http, android

I'm writing a relatively simple app for Android, which should get GPS coordinates and detect if the device is inside one of defined polygons. These polygon definitions I intend to download from a server through an unencrypted connection before the app launches its GPS activities. The polygon data is created by users and they should enter the address into the app and it will connect and download that JSON data.

So the main question is about that download process security: is it safe to transfer that data openly or should I bother with encryption?

One way I imagined is to make the users to encrypt the JSON data. Before they download it, they should input not only address, but also a password to decrypt that data, so the app can decrypt it after the download. Is there any point in doing this? Or should I do proper authorization (which I consider excessively complex for this case)?

Comment: Are you talking about custom encryption in addition to TLS for the app <-> server communication, or instead of it?

Comment: @Marc instead. I just request that file through http without authorization or anything.

Comment: If you ever need to ask yourself [do I need https](https://doesmysiteneedhttps.com/), the answer is YES! Don't use plain http, especially if the client is sending private information.

Comment: As @Marc mentioned, do use TLS for data transfers, there's no reason not to. Please don't roll your own cryptographic algorithms and be very aware of how you manage keys if implementing client side encryption.

Comment: Well the app doesn't send anything anywhere. Nor does this file have any sensitive or private data. That's why I was puzzled

Comment: You mentioned the app sending the address, that's pretty sensitive information. And please read the link I posted above, just because you don't serve sensitive data doesn't mean you should be completely insecure.

Comment: @Marc Yes yes, I have read that. Thank you.